# Dereferencing syntax in IA-32 assembly () or *?

Tags: assembly, att, x86

This is the source of confusion: 
**movl (%edx), %eax** This treats the value of %eax as an address, goes to it and copies its content to %eax,

Keeping that in mind then looking at:
**jmp *(%edx)** Since parenthesis was used earlier (as dereferencing in the mov instruction), then is the asterisk a form of double dereference ?

...and how would this instruction perform differently ? -->
**jmp (%edx)**

...or what about 
**jmp *%edx** versus **jmp %edx** ?

Comment: This is AT&T syntax, please keep it tagged that way.

Comment: Your first statement.. I think its a typo... Did you mean: "It treats the values of `%edx` as an address, goes to it and copies its contents to `%eax`"

Comment: You can check with a disassembler to see the last 2 are the same, and see the warning GAS prints about an indirect jump without `*`.  The only ambiguity is `jmp foo` (rel32) vs. `jmp *foo` (load from absolute address `foo` into EIP/RIP).

Answer (score 0):

The `*` indicates an absolute jump, in contrast with the absense of the asterisk meaning a relative jump.
See http://sourceware.org/binutils/docs-2.17/as/i386_002dMemory.html#i386_002dMemory

However, I don't know whether the assembler infers the absolute jump from the indirection even if the `*` is missing or it barks on the impossibility of an indirect relative jump.